# Logarithm Differentiation

Tags: calculus, derivatives, logarithms

I have the problem 
    $ y = \dfrac{(3x+1)^5 \times e^x}{\sqrt{2x^5+1}}$
I'm having a hard time with logarithm differentiation at first I was using the chain/product/quotient rules and i got a really long answer but obviously it was not the answer I needed. There are more steps to go through but for the life of me cant figure it out. If someone could help out id appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\quad{y = \dfrac{(3x+1)^5 \times e^x}{\sqrt{2x^5+1}}\\ \ln y = \ln\dfrac{(3x+1)^5 \times e^x}{\sqrt{2x^5+1}}\\\ln y=5\ln(3x+1)+x-\frac12\ln(2x^5+1)\\\frac{y'}{y}=5\frac{3}{3x+1}+1-\frac12.\frac{10x^4}{2x^5+1}\\\to \\y'=y\times(5\frac{3}{3x+1}+1-\frac12.\frac{10x^4}{2x^5+1})\\y'=\dfrac{(3x+1)^5 \times e^x}{\sqrt{2x^5+1}}\times(5\frac{3}{3x+1}+1-\frac12.\frac{10x^4}{2x^5+1})}$$

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense

Answer (score 3):

\begin{align}
y &= \frac{(3x+1)^5 e^x}{\sqrt{2x^5+1}}
\\
\log y &= 5 \log(3x+1) + x - \frac{1}{2} \log(2x^5+1)
\end{align}
Take the derivative of both sides to get $\frac{y'}{y} = ???$.
Then multiply both sides by $y$ and plug in the original expression for $y$.
This is computationally a bit simpler than using product/quotient rule on the original expression.